# want to use the var dump function but brings an error

Tags: php

things seem pretty much the same like the tutorial

```
<?php $s1 = "something";
var_dump ($s1)
```

want to var dump print and type the value
error stated: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING) in /home/wQdozU/prog.php on line 2

the site i use to write code in is https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler
if anyone also willing to we connect to learn code together or answer my questions is very well welcomed iam really eager and curious if you help it means a ton to me

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to you missing the semicolon on the variable assignment. Add a semicolon to the end of your lines and it should work.

```
<?php 
$s1 = "something";
var_dump ($s1);
```

Comment: thanks it worked iam new to progarming wanna connect

Comment: iam new to programing anyone want to connect with me